# Why won't my JFET Hartley oscillate

Tags: rf, oscillator, coil, amplitude-modulation

I built this Hartley oscillator (taken from the November 1990 edition of Popular Electronics) as part of an AM modulated signal generator project.  But, it steadfastly refused to oscillate.

[image]

I was careful about layout and built it on copper clad board, triple checking all connections and component values.  I even clocked the confusing reversal of drain and source.  Still nothing.

So, I modeled it in LTSpice and it doesn't oscillate there either, even after playing around with the values.  Is there something I'm missing here?  I'd still like to get this oscillating, since I've put some effort into its construction.

For parts I used an air blade variable cap (10 - 317pF) and an old RF transformer that I tuned to 255uH (to give me the low end of the MW band) on the primary (the tapped coil is about 7uH). I wound a new secondary to give me the 7uH I needed according to the 707VX spec (which has a 6:1 turns ratio).

[image]

Comment: Oscillators simulated with SPICE often fail to oscillate, and need starting off with a stimulus, such as a couple of cycles of the required frequency.

Comment: Fair enough, but it doesn't oscillate in real life either;-) I've built plenty of oscillators in spice and it's rare I can't get them to oscillate somehow.  This one is different.

Comment: I have used MPF102 before.  The Idss specification ranges from 2mA to 20mA (normal).  I found biasing a bit tricky.  Perhaps you could experiment with value of R3.  Perhaps increasing R3 to 1M. Bias current can be measured by measuring volts across R2. References from your LTspice.

Comment: Sorry, just realized the designated labels in spice image and original weren't the same - corrected now.

Comment: @Marla I tried a fair few values in the sim, without luck.  I've had issues with this jfet myself and it's normally a case of adjusting the source resistor.  But, not this time - so I'm wondering if there's something more fundamental here?

Comment: R3 is way too high. Try 270 ohms rather than k.

Comment: I think you've cracked it there Andy (again!).  Misprint, it looks like.  I'll try it out on the board later, but it looks better in the sim.

Comment: What about DS polarity of JFET .I have been told that sometimes DS can be swapped on some JFETs but have not tried it .You should swap DS to eliminate this as a possible issue .

Comment: @Autistic Apologies for the late response.  I spent most of today trying to get the circuit working (even after replacing R3).  Turns out the crappy ebay MPF102 JFETs were fake! They were NPN transistors.  Incredibly frustrating.  Anyway, got that sorted and then I had no time to swap D and S around.  But, I put the drain to R3, having little confidence in the schematic.  It worked fine.  Also, I used a POT for R1 and it turns out the optimal value for the best wave shape was 3K!

Comment: You might also try skipping your DC operating point solution, and turning the time step down.

Comment: @Buck8pe Please write this up as an answer and accept it if it solved the problem.

Comment: @pipe 2 not sure what the rules are, but I didn't write the comment that identified the problem.  Any aka wrote that.  If he wants to submit an answer, I'll gladly accept.  Incidentally, there's a follow on question that contains a revised circuit (one that works!) here (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296467/whats-the-purpose-of-the-diode-at-the-jfet-gate-in-this-hartley-oscillator)

Comment: @Buck8pe The rules are that comments do not answer questions, and can be removed at any time, in which case this solution will be lost. Andy knows this very well, and since you now know the actual solution to the problem, you can get easy points and help the answers-accepted rate by writing it yourself! Win-win. It is for example not clear to me what the problem was - wrong resistor or fake JFET?

Comment: @pipe Answer included.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the original Popular Electronics schematic had an error where R3, the drain resistance, was 1000 times bigger than it should have been.  It was printed as 270k when it should have been 270.

However, even with this error corrected, I found that the circuit performed poorly in reality.  Biasing was difficult and the resulting sine wave was distorted.  A much better circuit includes a diode at the gate to shift the DC level and bias the FET into its linear region.  The details of this circuit (along with a description of the diode function) can be found [in this stackexchange question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296467/whats-the-purpose-of-the-diode-at-the-jfet-gate-in-this-hartley-oscillator).

The issues I had with fake MPF102s, whilst annoying, had no bearing on the issue or its solution.

Finally, 100% of the solution credit is owed to Andy Aka.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take that credit LOL: -

[image]

R3 is far too high for this to begin oscillating. Try 270 ohms rather than 270 kohms.